# Connecting android device for debugging does not show in lsusb

Tags: 16.04, usb, android

I believe I've read all of the related posts on the web and now I'm reaching out for help.

I'm trying to connect my HTC 610 Desire Android 4.4.2 phone to my Ubuntu 16.06 desktop. My goal is to run with Android Developer Studio 2.1 to develop android apps.

I run lsusb with phone unplugged:

```
thomas@thomas-desktop:/var/log$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 17f6:0822 Unicomp, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Plug the phone in and try again:

```
thomas@thomas-desktop:/var/log$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 17f6:0822 Unicomp, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So no change with that. What's up with that? I looked in the system log, but don't see anything instructive.

I have created the 51-android-rules file. Here's the contents:

```
thomas@thomas-desktop:/var/log$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

With both the old and new HTC vendor ID since I'm not sure which one's mine. I added my user to plugdev group.

Here's my fuse file:

```
thomas@thomas-desktop:/var/log$ cat /etc/fuse.conf 
# /etc/fuse.conf - Configuration file for Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)

# Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.
# The default is 1000.
#mount_max = 1000

# Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options.
user_allow_other
```

I have enabled USB Debugging on my phone and selected Verify apps over USB. When I plug my phone in, it indicates that it's charging over the cable from my computer, but nothing else.

I now have nothing else to look at and am stuck.

Comment: Make sure the phone is set to PTP or MTP mode. Otherwise, (for some stupid reason) you won't be able to connect to it over ADB.

Comment: My Alcatel smartphone I just plugged in and Nautilus saw it in Kernel version 3.13. After upgrade to Kernel 4.4 "USB Driver" would show up, eject that and then "Android" would show up with Internal storage and SD card visible. I didn't have to setup any udev 51-android-rules file like you have done. So I wonder if that might be breaking it? I did update the USB ID's file so my phone name showed up properly. Not an answer I know "just a comment" :)

Comment: @AndroidDev My HTC Desire 610 does not have a menu on the storage screen to allow me to change the mode. Do you know how to change this on this phone?

Comment: @Thom - Hrrmmm... does it show up using the ***same cable*** on a Windows box?

Comment: @Thom Based on the description in your question, changing the mode wouldn't matter in the OS detecting a connection.  Changing the mode will determine how the connection is used or if it has access permission at all.  If the OS doesn't recognize the connection as what you have described, the culprit is either the cable or the connection usb connector on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I plugged the same phone into my Windows computer it behaved exactly the same way. I bought a Samsung Galaxy Tablet E and plugged it in and it worked immediately.

This leads me to believe that the problem is the HTC Desire 610, which doesn't seem to work with the Android development environment. So, for now, I'm moving on with the Tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and test results from your question the culprit is a **hardware issue**:

The most likely culprit is the cable.

Some issues with the cable:

- **Possibly a charging cable** - a computer won't recognize a charging cable.  Try changing the cable to ensure you have a functioning data cable.
- **Possibly a damaged cable** - some of the connections in the cable may not be loose.  There are occasions where shaking a cable will affect his functionality.  Those are occasions of damaged cables.  I've also seen occasions where a cable will work with some devices on the same PC and not function with other devices.  I've also seen occasions where some cables will work with some phones and not other phones.  All those occasions have either been because of very cheap cables which may have become damaged easier than some of the more expensive cables.
- **Possibly a damaged connector on the phone** - I have seen many occasions where a cable might not charge, or connect to the computer even with a good cable.  The resulting culprit was the connector on the phone, of which replacing the connector resolved the issue.

It might be a different problem, but it checking out those common problems could save some time.

Comment: Never said it was a charging cable.

Comment: @Thom I offered input on what I thought would be a most likely culprit.  I have helped a number of people having problems.  Also searching the internet this as a culprit isn't that rare... just trying to help with a possible solution.  I also suggested that you try a different cable.  I have seen occasions, even in my environment when just changing the cable resolved the issue.  Also I've seen where a cable works on a number of computers and a number of devices, but for some reason it has problems with a particular computer.   Those are the two main culprits in my answer.